# How can I use Mixpanel in Iran?

Tags: block, mixpanel

Mixpanel is using "SoftLayer" which blocks all the request from IPs coming from Iran. Is there a workaround to redirect these request to IPs in another country to be able to bypass their filter and send the data to Mixpanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways depending on your configuration and platform

what is your hosting? If its shared then your options are limited but if you deployed your application on a dedicated server or VPS you can route your traffic via transparent proxies or through a vpn tunnel. And there are many services for that either!

for example [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is a well-documented and easy to use service for that! But keep in mind that it works better on linux! you can read these articles for configuring a transparent proxy with squid: [On Ubuntu](https://veesp.com/en/blog/how-to-setup-squid-on-ubuntu), On [CentOS](http://linuxtechlab.com/squid-transparent-proxy-server-complete-configuration/)

**But given the circumstances I recommend using an open-source analytical system such as:**

[Matomo](https://matomo.org/) (formerly known as Piwik)

[Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/)

[Heap](https://heapanalytics.com/) (a famous iranian event site ([Evand](http://evand.com)) was using Heap)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect through a [VPN tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network). It works the way that you connect to a computer somewhere else (in your case in another country) and then you connect from that computer to the rest of the internet. So from the rest of the internet it looks like you're somewhere else.

You can check out [ProtonVPN](https://protonvpn.com/), they have VPN tunnels through a bunch of countries.